# How to get the status of a Twilio Notification using the sid?

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

I am using the Notifications APIs (Twilio Java SDK version 7.24.2). I've successfully sent the SMSes using the Notification API like:

`private String sendMessageThroughNotificationService(String message, PhoneNumber receiverPhoneNumber){
        Notification notification = Notification.creator(twilioNotificationSID)
                                    .setBody(message)
                                    .setToBinding(Promoter.listOfOne("{\"binding_type\":\"sms\", \"address\":\""+receiverPhoneNumber.toString()+"\"}"))
                                    .create();
        return notification.getSid();
    }`

Now, what should I do if I want to get the Notification's status through the SID of the notification that I am returning from the above method?
Does Twilio's Java Notification's API provide any way to find the Notification's status through its SID (if I don't want to use the register callback URL approach)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

If you are only sending one notification at a time via SMS, then I recommend you just use the [Messages API](https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/send-messages). That way the API will return the Message SID, which you can then use to [look up the Message with the API](https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/api/message?code-sample=code-fetch-message&code-language=java&code-sdk-version=7.x) and check its status.

There is no way to look up all the messages sent via Notify in order to check their statuses. The recommended method there is to register a `StatusCallbackUrl` to get updates on each status.

Let me know if that helps at all.

Comment: Yup, that was what I thought initially while posting this. However, I wasn't sure. Thank you for confirming.

Comment: Hello, now 6 years after this reply i want to ask if now it's possible to get the message status of each message that i send using the Notify api? Thanks and sorry for my bad English.

Comment: The recommendation remains to set up a `statusCallbackUrl` so that you receive the status updates as they happen.