# When using Twilio Notify API to send bulk SMS, how to tie status webhook callbacks to the original message?

Tags: java, twilio, twilio-api

When sending SMS using the Notify API, I get back a Notify sid.

```
Body:
  "sid":"NT49cefe1c684f470648e59883c1bcc556",
```

In the dashboard at Twilio.com, I've configured Notify with a Messaging Service.  That Messaging Service has been configured to call my custom web service (webhook in Twilio terminology).  I am getting status coming through for every binding the message was sent to, but no ID of the originating Notify 'event' so I can tie them together.

I was expecting to see the "NT" id somewhere.

```
Body:
  SmsSid=SM89ca8924434306734be97ecb28c5b5cc
  SmsStatus=delivered
  MessageStatus=delivered
  MessagingServiceSid=MG767836bd41ab8b07c00d41582f15f2a1
  MessageSid=SM89ca8924434306734be97ecb28c5b5cc
```

How can I tie these webhook statuses to the originating Notify?

Answer (score 0):

Twilio provides no way to link notifications to the individual messages. (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/52157927/1196148)

***However***, you can use the [`status_callback`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/notify/api/notification-resource#create-a-notification-resource) parameter to specify a custom webhook URL that is unique to this notification. Add an extra parameter so the webhook can find the resource that triggered the notification:

```php
$notification = $client
    ->notify->services( $serviceSid )
    ->notifications->create( [
        "toBinding" => [
            '{"binding_type":"sms", "address":"+15555555555"}',
            '{"binding_type":"sms", "address":"+16666666666"}',
        ],
        "body" => "Hello",
        "sms" => [
            "status_callback" => "https://example.com/status/?id=" . $some_id,
        ],
    ] );
```